# Cannot set tap interface up using C++

Tags: c++, interface, wireshark, tap, ifconfig

I was able to create a persistent ***tap*** interface using this [reference](https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/). Now I am trying to make the interface up using like this:

`fd = iff_alloc(tap_name, IFF_TAP|IFF_NO_PI|IFF_UP);`

However, I still see that the interface is down when I use the command `ip link show`:

```
`~/eclipse-workspace/RTI-swapper$ ip link show  | grep  tap0

6: tap0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state 
DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500`
```

Also, I am unable to see this interface in Wireshark. I can only see a tap interface on Wireshark when I create it manually from the terminal, for example:

```
openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
ip link set tap0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tap0
```

Could anyone help me know how to make a new tap interface visible to wireshark from my C++ code ?

Comment: what is `if_alloc` function here?

Comment: It stands for interface allocate. It is equivalent to `tun_alloc` in the reference link